# How LeakCanary gets installed and ready only by adding to the dependencies?

Tags: android, dependencies, leakcanary

This a bit odd or I have some misunderstanding about dependencies. How LeakCanary can be installed and ready to observe my application for memory leaks only by adding it to the dependencies in the app's Gradle file?

Comment: You can find some info here https://square.github.io/leakcanary/fundamentals/#how-does-leakcanary-work

Comment: Doesn't explain how LeakCanary works only by adding to the dependencies.

Comment: The code is open source , so the best way would be to clone the code and check it your self .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Android, Content providers are created after the Application instance is created but before Application.onCreate() is called. LeakCanary has a ContentProvider defined in the library AndroidManifest.xml file. When that ContentProvider is installed, LeakCanary adds activity and fragment lifecycle listeners to the application.

Comment: Thank you. You made me realize how important it is to examine merged manifest.